# ios - Vertical position is ambiguous

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I've a regular table view and I'm putting a view above and below the cell currently in the middle. On some occasion, those "above" and "below" cells don't appear because `Vertical position is ambiguous`. I don't see the ambiguity. My views structure looks like

[image] ans here's a screenshot of the contraints on the above cell:

[image]

As you can see, constraints related to vertical positioning are:

- bottom of the view
- height

And I don't see how this leaves room for uncertainty regarding the positioning of this view.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be putting **any** views inside a table view, either table view cells or other views. You define cell prototypes and then the table view creates and places cells as needed based on the data source.

Comment: That sounds right. I get that Apple is doing a few things within the table view that are not expecting other views to be around. Still I'd expect that as long as the constraint make sense, there should be no fondamental issue.

Comment: Table view cells are in charge of their content views, but the table view owns it's view hierarchy and you should not be messing with it.